# Surjectivity of character module map implies injective module map?

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules, flatness, injective-module

I'm trying to understand modules. And I want to know, by definition of a module $M$, the underlying group structure on $M$ is abelian. Does that mean that every $R$ module $M$ is also a $\mathbb{Z}$ module because of the underlying structure?

Is this why we can define the character module $M^* = Hom_\mathbb{Z}(M,\mathbb{Q}/\mathbb{Z})$?

I'm really trying to prove that a module map $M \to N$ is injective iff the dual map $N^* \to M^*$ is surjective. Now I know in general the reverse is not true if $M^* = Hom_R(M,R)$. The question being so ominous makes me think that the "dual" map should be a map between the character modules. So I want to use the fact that $\mathbb{Q}/\mathbb{Z}$ is an injective $\mathbb{Z}$ module, but I'm not sure if I can apply this functor $Hom_\mathbb{Z}({-},\mathbb{Q}/\mathbb{Z})$ to any module.

Comment: Yes, every module is a $\mathbb{Z}$-module.

Comment: $\mathbb{Z}$ is an initial object in the category of rings, i.e.  for every ring $R$ there exists a unique ring homomorphism $\mathbb{Z}\rightarrow R$. An $R$-module structure on an abelian group $M$ is the same data as a choice of ring homomorphism $R\rightarrow\operatorname{End}(M)$, so for $R=\mathbb{Z}$, we get that every abelian group has a unique $\mathbb{Z}$-module structure. If you already have an $R$-module structure, you can compose $R\rightarrow\operatorname{End}(M)$ with the unique $\mathbb{Z}\rightarrow R$ to obtain this map and interpret it as restriction of scalars.